# ORA-00907 Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, join

I got error message

> "ora-00907  Missing Right Parenthesis" for this query in Excel VBA
>   (Oracle ODBC ADO):

```
SELECT SELOKGY.GYAR, SELOK.SELOKID, SELOK.NEV, SELOK.AKTIV, SELOK.CSOP1, SELOKCS.SZINT, SELOKCS.NEV, SELOKCS.LEMEZGEP, SELOKCS.FELDOLGOZOGEP, SELOK.CSOP2, SELOKCS_1.SZINT, SELOKCS_1.NEV, SELOKCS_1.LEMEZGEP, SELOKCS_1.FELDOLGOZOGEP, SELOK.CSOP3, SELOKCS_2.SZINT, SELOKCS_2.NEV, SELOKCS_2.LEMEZGEP, SELOKCS_2.FELDOLGOZOGEP 
FROM SELOKGY RIGHT JOIN (SELOKCS AS SELOKCS_2 RIGHT JOIN (SELOKCS AS SELOKCS_1 RIGHT JOIN (SELOKCS RIGHT JOIN SELOK ON SELOKCS.KOD = SELOK.CSOP1) ON SELOKCS_1.KOD = SELOK.CSOP2) ON SELOKCS_2.KOD = SELOK.CSOP3) ON SELOKGY.SELOK = SELOK.SELOKID 
WHERE (((SELOKGY.GYAR)=1 Or (SELOKGY.GYAR)=2)) 
ORDER BY SELOKGY.GYAR, SELOKCS.SZINT, SELOKCS.NEV, SELOKCS_1.SZINT, SELOKCS_1.NEV, SELOKCS_2.SZINT, SELOKCS_2.NEV
```

Please help me to find the mistake. Thanks

Comment: remove the Parenthesis. in joins. you do not need them

Comment: Whole `Aliasing` is messed up. Use simple alias for tablename

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your SQL:

1) Oracle does not support the `as` keyword for **table** aliases:

```
SELOKCS AS SELOKCS_1
```

It should be:

```
SELOKCS SELOKCS_1
```

2) Your join syntax is wrong, with parentheses were none are needed. Do it more like:

```
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t2.xx = t1.xx
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t3.xx = t3.xx
... etc.
```

Your SQL suffers from "parenthitis" in fact - e.g.

```
(((SELOKGY.GYAR)=1 Or (SELOKGY.GYAR)=2))
```

Is really just:

```
(SELOKGY.GYAR=1 Or SELOKGY.GYAR=2)
```

That could even be reduced in this case to:

```
SELOKGY.GYAR=1 Or SELOKGY.GYAR=2
```

... but I prefer to keep parentheses around `OR` conditions in case I later add an `AND`.  However there is a neater way still here:

```
SELOKGY.GYAR in (1,2)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra opening parenthesis in Where clause

> WHERE (((SELOKGY.GYAR)=1 Or (SELOKGY.GYAR)=2))

Remove the first opening after Where clause.

**WHERE ((SELOKGY.GYAR)=1 Or (SELOKGY.GYAR)=2)) **

Comment: there are 2 opening parenthesis and 2 closeing parenthesis so the Count fits. Should not be the problem